# Sum of each element's length in Python

Tags: python, list

How to calculate sum of each element of list in python3? Although I could do it, are there any smart ways?

```
data = [[1,2],[1], [3,4,2]]
sum_length = 0
for d in data:
    sum_length += len(d)
print(sum_length) # 6
```

Comment: You can do it with ``sum(map(len, data))``

Comment: @RaymondHettinger a particularly pretty solution, especially on Python 3.

Comment: Thank you, @RaymondHettinger

Comment: FWIW, this isn't an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780403 which is specifically about a list of strings, while this is a question about a list of lists.   The answer to both would be same though.

Answer (score 6):

The shortest and fastest way is apply a [functional programming style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) with [*map()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [*sum()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
>>> data = [[1,2],[1], [3,4,2]]
>>> sum(map(len, data))
6
```

In Python 2, use [*itertools.imap*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) instead of *map* for better memory performance:

```
>>> from itertools import imap
>>> data = ['a', 'bc', 'def', 'ghij']
>>> sum(imap(len, data))
10
```