# Sum of the lengths of all elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, string-length

How do I figure out the sum of the lengths of all elements of a list?

I have a list and I want to figure out the sum of the lengths of the elements

Example:

```
a_list = ["  ", " ", " ", " "]  # 2+1+1+1 = 5
```

The sum of lengths here would be 5. All elements of the list will be strings if that matters.

I tried `sum(list_of_spaces, key=len)` but that syntax seemed to be wrong. Tbh the whole concept of `key=` is still a bit unclear to me. But I'll figure that out in time.

I could use a for-loop with a counter of sort to figure the sum out but I'd like to know it there's a way to use `sum` or similar function to solve the matter so that i could use the sum of lengths directly in a condition without fiddling with loops and counters.

Comment: `sum(len(i) for i in a_list)`

Comment: `sum` doesn't take a `key` argument; that's something `max`, `min`, and `sorted` support (the common thread being all three require comparisons of elements in the sequence).

Comment: use `print(sum([len(e) for e in a_list]))`

Comment: You could do this: `sum(map(len,a_list))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Sum string lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780403/python-sum-string-lengths)